# Subscript to fractions

Tags: subscripts, fractions

How do I write this in Latex. I've looked everywhere and to be honest I don't even know how to describe it in google search bar.

I have

```
$$(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t})_(t=0)$$
```

but it's the last part that does work properly

[image: This]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Note that you shouldn't be using `$$ .. $$` for display math, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Try `_{t=0}` instead of  `_(t=0)`.

Comment: If you are still learning, a good way is to use this [Latex equation editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). Since it has pre-made code it was easy for me to quickly learn the syntax for representing complex equations by examining common components and symbols. It's a good place to experiment.

Answer (score 7):

The underscore character (`_`) will make only one math atom a subscript. In the case of your code, it was the `(`. To make it work you have to group the `t=0` using braces (`{...}`).

Also, use `\left(` and `\right)` instead of just `(` and `)` to make the parentheses taller for the fraction.

Finally, use `\[` and `\]` to delimit the display math instead of `$$` ([reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/134574)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)_{t=0}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is perfect thank you. I meant to use the curly brackets instead of the normal ones but I would have never of figured t out. And I was just going to ask you how to make the brackets taller. Also, I will try the \[ instead of $$ It all works, thank you very much and hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using a dedicated package like `esdiff` to simplify typing. It defined a `\diffp{function}{variables}` command. In addition, the order of crossed partial derivatives is automatically calculated. The evaluation point of partial derivatives is added in the `\diffp*` command:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}

 \begin{document}

\[ \diffp*{u}{t}{t = 0}\qquad \diffp{u}{t x}\qquad \diffp{u}{{t^2} x}\]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I not known this solution. +1 for all.